# How to make https://...zoom.us links open directly in Zoom app (not browser first) on Mac?

Tags: macos, web-browser, zoom, zoom.app

On mac OS Catalina, links I'm sent by calendar invites and Zoom, looking like https://...zoom.us/s/1234567, open first in a browser (Firefox) and then the Zoom app comes up. Can I somehow have the OS skip the browser step and directly open the link in the App (run the App directly)?

Comment: The link given as "similar question" is several years old and does not provide a solution to the problem.